# Spivak: Show that $f(kx+(1-k)y)<kf(x)+(1-k)f(y)$ whenever $k$ is a rational number, between $0$ and $1$, of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

Here is a starred problem from Spivak's chapter on "Convexity and Concavity"

> *7.
>
> (a) Prove that if $f$ is convex, then
> $f(\frac{x+y}{2})<\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$.
>
> (b) Suppose that $f$ satisfies this condition. Show that
> $$f(kx+(1-k)y)<kf(x)+(1-k)f(y)\tag{1}$$ whenever $k$ is a rational number,
> between $0$ and $1$, of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$. Hint: part $(a)$ is
> the special case $n=1$. Use induction, employing part $(a)$ at each
> step.

To cut to the chase:
**Though I understand the proof provided by the solution manual, I don't know what exactly was proved in an intuitive sense. I am looking for an intuitive explanation for what part b) is showing.**

**First question:** "Suppose that $f$ satisfies this condition" means we are assuming that $f(\frac{x+y}{2})<\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$?

Part $(a)$ is relatively easy

> $f$ convex means
>
> $$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}>\frac{f(\frac{x+y}{2})-f(x)}{\frac{y-x}{2}}=\frac{2(f(\frac{x+y}{2})-f(x))}{y-x}$$
>
> $$\implies f(\frac{x+y}{2})<\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$

Part $(b)$ is relatively harder.

The statement to be proved seems to be, in my own words

> If the average of the function values at $x$ and $y$ is above the
> value of the function at $\frac{x+y}{2}$, then the weighted average of
> the function values is above the value of the function at the weighted
> $x$-coordinates, where the weights are rational numbers in $[0,1]$
> that sum to $1$ and of form $\frac{m}{2^n}$.

- Apparently, it is required to show that the statement is true for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, though this is not stated.
- Given an $n$, there are a limited number of choices for $m$, if we assume that the rational number $k$ is in lowest form. For example, for $n=1$, $m$ must be 1, ie $k=\frac{1}{2}$; if it were $2$, $k$ wouldn't be in lowest terms, and if it were $>2$ then $k$ would be larger than 1.
- Another example: $n=2$. $m$ must be either $1$ or $3$, ie $k=\frac{1}{4}$ or $k=\frac{3}{4}$.
- One more example: $n=3$. $m$ must either be $1$, $3$, $5$, or $7$, ie $k$ is either $\frac{1}{8}$, $\frac{3}{8}$, $\frac{5}{8}$, or $\frac{7}{8}$.

**Here is the proof in the solution manual**

The assertion is true for $n=1$, ie $k=1/2$. Suppose that for some $n$ it is true for all $x$ and $y$. If $k=m/2^{n+1}$ is in lowest terms, then $m$ is odd. Consequently, $k_1=(m-1)/2^{n+1}$ and $k_2=(m+1)/2^{n+1}$ can be expressed in the form $a/2^n$, so the assertion is true for $k_1$ and $k_2$. Notice also that $k=(k_1+k_2)/2$. From the result for $k_1$ and $k_2$, and the assertion for $n=1$ applied to $x'=k_1x+(1-k_1)y$ and $y'=k_2x+(1-k_2)y$ we obtain

$$f(kx+(1-k)y)=f(\frac{x'+y+}{2})<\frac{f(x')}{2}+\frac{f(y')}{2}$$

$$<\frac{k_1f(x)+(1-k_1)f(y)}{2}+\frac{k_2f(x)+(1-k_2)f(y)}{2}$$

$$=kf(x)+(1-k)f(y)$$

Note that the part that reads $\frac{x'+y+}{2}$ is copied verbatim from the solution manual. Seems to be a typo there on the $y+$.

Now I understand the individual steps in the proof (the solution manual is quite terse, so a careful redoing with explicit steps is useful to understand it).

**But what exactly has been proved in part b?**

Also, why the assumption that $k$ is rational?

**At risk of making the question too long, I will add here my commented version of the solution manual solution**

By assumption

$$\forall x\ \forall y,\ f(\frac{x+y}{2})<\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}\tag{2}$$

This represents the $n=1$ base case of our proof by induction, ie that the statement

$$\forall x\ \forall y,\ f(kx+(1-k)y)<kf(x)+(1-k)f(y)\tag{1}$$

is true when $k$ is a rational number between $0$ and $1$ of form $\frac{1}{2}$.

Now suppose the statement is true when $k$ is a rational number between $0$ and $1$ of form $\frac{m}{2^n}$ for some $n$, where the fraction is in lowest terms.

Our question is: is the assertion true when $k$ is of form $\frac{m}{2^{n+1}}$

If it is then we will have shown that the statement is true for all rational $k$ between $0$ and $1$ of form $\frac{m}{2^n}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

To answer our question, we note that if $k=\frac{m}{2^{n+1}}$, then $m$ must be odd, otherwise it'd have a factor of $2$ in common with the denominator.

But then $m-1$ and $m+1$ are even, and have a factor $2$ in common with $2^{n+1}$. Hence if $k_1=\frac{m-1}{2^{n+1}}$ and $k_2=\frac{m+1}{2^{n+1}}$, then each can be written as $\frac{a}{2^{n_1}}$, where $n_1<n$.

For example, if $n+1=5$ and $m=7$ then $k=\frac{m}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{7}{32}$. Then $k_1=\frac{m-1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{4}{32}=\frac{2}{2^4}=\frac{1}{2^3}$.

Seems that the inductive hypothesis should be that $(1)$ is true for all numbers $\leq n$. After all as the example showed, only $\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}=\frac{1}{2^3}$ is in lowest terms.

Anyway, we conclude that $(1)$ is true for $k_1$ and $k_2$, because they satisfy this (strong) inductive hypothesis.

But $\frac{k_1+k_2}{2}=k$.

Take two points

$$x'=k_1x+(1-k_1)y$$

$$y'=k_2x+(1-k_2)y$$

Then

$$\frac{x'+y'}{2}=\frac{k_1+k_2}{2}x+\frac{2-k_1-k_2}{2}y=kx+(1-k)y$$

Therefore,

$$f(kx+(1-k)y)=f(\frac{x'+y'}{2})<\frac{f(x')}{2}+\frac{f(y')}{2}$$

where we have used the fact that $(2)$ is true for all $x$ and $y$ including $x'$ and $y'$.

But we also know that $f(x')=f(k_1x+(1-k_1)y)$ and $(1)$ holds for $k_1$, and $f(y')=f(k_2x+(1-k_2)y)$ and $(1)$ also holds for $k_2$.

Hence we have

$$f(kx+(1-k)y)=f(\frac{x'+y'}{2})<\frac{f(x')}{2}+\frac{f(y')}{2}$$

$$<\frac{k_1f(x)+(1-k_1)f(y)}{2}+\frac{k_2f(x)+(1-k_2)f(y)}{2}$$

$$=\frac{k_1+k_2}{2}f(x)+(1-\frac{k_1+k_2}{2})f(y)$$

$$=kf(x)+(1-k)f(y)$$

**Again I understand the steps, but what is the usefulness of this result, and what was the point of this exercise?**

Comment: Yes, a typo.. Read $y+$ as $y'$ - Thanks.

Comment: draw a line segment from a vertex at 0 to the other vertex at 1.  And mark in red pen some arbitrary point $p$ in the interior.  Now divide the line segment in half (by drawing in a vertex at $0.5$). Now divide those 2 line segments in half, then divide those 4 line segments in half and so on. This repeated (barycentric) subdivision means that you eventually get your red dot arbitrarily close to some vertex that resulted from this  process.  If $f$ is continuous this could be quite valuable. **Note:** technically (a) is wrong -- it needs to say both $x\neq y$ and that $f$ is *strictly convex*.

Comment: As an aside, convex implies $\le$ not $<$. A linear functional is convex.

Comment: Perhaps the point is to show that midpoint convexity is almost sufficient to imply convexity. In fact, with an extra assumption of measurability, then it is sufficient.

Comment: @copper.hat There are two definitions of convexity in Spivak. One is "a function $f$ is convex on an interval if for all $a$ and $b$ in the interval, the line segment joining $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ lies above the graph of $f$. A linear function isn't convex according to this definition, correct?

Comment: Spivak's definition of convexity is that of strict convexity. Just to emphasize — because you asked for an intuitive explanation:  b) is showing that *at rational points* along the segment $[x,y]$ the function is indeed below the chord joining $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$.

Comment: @user8675309 Now I understand the $k=\frac{m}{2^n}$: these are the halfway points of the line segments obtained by splitting previous segments in half. The statement that was proved is basically that: if for any endpoints forming a line segment we can split the line segment in half and the value of the function at that halfway point is below the average of the value of the function at the endpoints of the line segment, then we can keep splitting line segments and the relationship between function value at halfway mark and average function value at endpoints is true for all the splits.

Comment: @user8675309 So intuitively this seems to mean that the relationship will be true for all numbers (though we haven't proved this, and I am not sure if it is in fact true). This is also related to your point about the red dot. This is intuitively true, but we haven't proved it, right?

Comment: *"So intuitively this seems to mean that the relationship will be true for all number"*. Your intuition is correct *iff*  is continuous. A standard exercise is to show that being convex ⟹ continuity. The other direction is that if  is continuous you can evaluate the limit of the sequence $t_r f\big(x\big) + (1-t_r)f \big(y\big) - f\big(t_r x + (1-t_r)y\big)\geq 0$ where $t_r$ is the closest vertex to your red dot at iteration $r$ of (barycentric) subdivision. Note condition (b) is technically called a J-convex which is of historical importance; convex is a proper subset J-convex.